# Spring Boot DB connection release mode

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-mybatis

Is there a way to control database connection release strategy in Spring Boot? Something like Hibernate's `ConnectionReleaseMode`?

My test code would be rougly following:

1. INSERT query
2. HTTP call
3. UPDATE query

INSERT and UPDATE queries are their own methods in a repository bean (either extending CrudRepository, or as a Mybatis @Mapper). HTTP call is in it's own bean.

Now my service bean is where I experiment with different `@Transactional` settings as my ultimate goal is to have these three steps executed within a single transaction.

The problem is, the HTTP call can take hundreds of millis and Spring is holding the database connection during that time. This quickly leads to an empty connection pool, while the connections themselves are idle.

I have done the same experiments with default configuration using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and also using `mybatis-spring-boot-starter`.

The only thing which got me closer to my goal was setting `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` for `data-jpa`, which would release db connections in case of not using `@Transactional` at all or with propagation set to `NEVER`. It doesn't work if it's all wrapped in a transactin though.

I'm feeling like I'm missing some vital part of the transaction concept in Spring. Though the Spring [reference docs mentions release mode](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#orm-jpa-jta) only in relation to JTA transaction manager + JEE container + Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Transactions are bound to a connection/session so you can't release the connection in the middle of a transaction. You have to finish the transaction to close/release the connection. Keep in mind that a transaction could abort at any time, and since the HTTP call is not "part of" the transaction, but just runs while the transaction is in progress, it won't help you to keep the transaction open while the HTTP call is running. I'd suggest you go with one of the following solutions:

1. Use a circuit breaker to cancel the HTTP call if it hits a timeout to have an upper bound for how long a connection/transaction can be open/held
2. Move the HTTP call out of the transaction, either before or after the transaction
3. Use two database transactions

Note that you could use a transactional Job Scheduler to schedule a job in the first TX. The job could then, with at least once semantics, try to invoke the HTTP call and then continue with the second transaction or do some compensation if something fails.